# JNI callback passed to C

Tags: java, c++, c, callback, java-native-interface

I have a java callback function I want to pass to a C++ wrapper that will in turn pass it to a C/C++ function.

How would I do this?

I imagine the wrapper has to create some type of C++ lambda function or something along those lines to resolve the parameters.

**Edit:**

Here are the callbacks signature in C. I will be implementing these in java. (atleast some of them)

```
typedef struct ASIOCallbacks
{
    void (*bufferSwitch) (long doubleBufferIndex, ASIOBool 
    void (*sampleRateDidChange) (ASIOSampleRate sRate);
    long (*asioMessage) (long selector, long value, void* message, double* opt);
    ASIOTime* (*bufferSwitchTimeInfo) (ASIOTime* params, long doubleBufferIndex, ASIOBool directProcess);
} ASIOCallbacks;
```

BTW: ASIOTime *params will never be used.
I setup the callbacks in a C function. Here's the path...

Java passes callbacks to C++ wrapper. C++ wrapper passes them to C function to setup the callbacks.

Comment: The function to call back is the java function, and you call it from C/c++ ?   Or do you have a native function in java, that call the C/C++ function/wrapers ?

Comment: I call the callback from C/C++.

Comment: Ok, can you post the java signature of the callback (i.e. static or not, return type, arguments with type, name, name of the class) ?

Comment: The class would be called "Callbacks". They will be non-static. The callbacks will be passed from java to C++ through a java class.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've already invoqued somewhere in your C++ code the JVM and the JNI environment that will host your java functions:

```
JavaVM *jvm;                // Pointer to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine)
JNIEnv *env;                // Pointer to native interface
...                         // initialisation of these
```

Let's look at the first example:

Your **java** function will be something like:

```
public class Callback {
    public static void bufferSwitch (long index, ASIOBool b);  
}
```

I guess you already have something like ASIOBool type implemented in Java.  If not you'll have to.

Now you can write a **C++ wrapper**:

```
class Callback { 
public: 
    static void bufferSwitch (long index, ASIOBool b);
    ...
};
void Callback::bufferSwitch (long index, ASIOBool b) {
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Callback"); // loads the Java class
    if (cls==nullptr) 
        throw exception("Java class not found"); 
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "bufferSwitch","(JLASIOBool;)V"); 
    if (mid==nullptr)
        throw exception("Java method with appropriate signature not found");
    // primitive types can be passed by value
    // but for the other we must build an object
    jclass cls2 = env->FindClass("ASIOBool"); // loads the Java class
    if (cls2==nullptr) 
        throw exception("Java class not found"); 
    jmethodID ctor = env->GetMethodID(cls2, "<init>", "()V");
    if (ctor==nullptr) 
        throw exception("Java class constructor not found"); 
    jobject jb = env->NewObject(cls2, ctor);

    // ... to do:  you have to initialize the Java ASIOBool object with the C++ ASIOBool components
    // so if it's only a bool, better use the fundamental java type Boolean
    // to avoid building a java object from C++

    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls2, mid, (jlong)index, jb);  // FINALLY WE CAN CALL !
    env->DeleteLocalRef(jb);   // tell the java garbage collector that we no longer use the tmp object

}
```

Note that for every Java object (aka not the basic types) used as parameter, you have to provide the signature. The [fundamental types are coded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp276) as a letter.  The other types/classes start with L followed by the full class name and a semicolumn.   For classes which appear in packages, you have to specify the full name (ex:  "Ljava/lang/String;" for java strings).

To learn more:  [C++ JNI tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI) and [C JNI tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI).

Comment: You should add explicit details about initializing JNIEnv from JavaVM and attaching the current thread, cf [this code](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/native/callback.c#L623).

Comment: I believe the first parameter of any JNI function is the JNIEnv. And thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @CalebMerchant the first parameter of the JNI function is the env, in the C interface.  If used in cpp code, the JNI functions adopt the OO convention:  env is the main object, and you call the function with env->function